# Android: Intended use of fragments with services, dialogs etc

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've been creating android apps for a few months now and I'm having trouble with the intended use of `Fragments`.

`Fragments` are supposed to be reusable UI components but how far do you make them stand alone?

One of the `Fragments` I've created is a `ListFragment` of downloadable videos. At the moment I've implemented all the methods inside the `Fragment` with little or none of the methods calling the host `Activity`. The `Fragment` calls the `Activity` for a few minor things but everything like downloading files and finding them on external storage is done by the `Fragment`.

90% of the time I find it's the easiest way of implementing it but there's some times it just doesn't work.

An example is a confirmation dialog for deleting a video in my `ListFragment`. The dialog is a `DialogFragment` so is attached to the `Activity` but all the UI update and deletion methods are inside the `ListFragment`. So I end up with the `DialogFragment` calling the `Activity` just to call the `ListFragment`.

Another example is binding to a `Service`. Do I bind the `Activity` to the `Service` or just the `Fragment`? The `Activity` has no use for the `Service` but is a `Fragment` supposed to be doing all the work of starting and maintaining a `Service`? If not it means all the `Fragments` calls to the `Service` have to go through the `Activity` so the `Fragment` is no longer stand alone.

I'm wondering if I'm taking the stand alone idea too far, is a `Fragment` instead supposed to be minimally self-contained and actually rely on the `Activity` hosting it for all the heavy lifting?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A very interesting question!

I usually try to keep my fragments as isolated as possible. That means I usually don't let them know about anything around them except for their own activity. It's then the activity's role (if you ask me) to provide what-ever-is-needed to the fragment.

In practice this means that my fragments never own their own content, like a content provider or a custom DAO. The activity (or - God forbid - the application) owns it and then provides only a subset of the data, like a cursor, a domain object or an adapter, to the fragment.

This also means that when a fragment modifies an item it has to ask the activity to persist the changes. Or if an item is to be deleted, the fragment has to ask the activity to show the corresponding UI for that operation (yes, it's technically possible to let a fragment show another fragment, but I usually try to avoid it as far as possible).

When it comes to services and binding to them I really don't know what to suggest as it really depends on the service and what it's doing. If you're downloading new content from the internet in your service, then it seems rectified to let the activity handle the binding (as it is the activity that needs to save the data, according to previous discussion). If you, on the other hand, are calculating something specific, based on your isolated data (e.g. decrypting a file or so), then it might make sence to let the fragment handle that part.

In an even greater perspective one soon realizes that a setup, such as described above, will give birth to quite some callback interfaces as each fragment needs to establish a contract to its activity. Hence, for smaller projects it sometimes happens that I override my very own fragment-pardigms.

I also can't help noticing that when using fragments, my applications tend to be very MVC oriented in their architecture. I leave it to you and any future readers to decide wether it's a good or bad thing ;-)

Cheers

Comment: Thanks! I'm happy to share my experience, and even more happy you find it useful :-)